Spring Boot 3.2.1 and spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory 5.11.0
I'm attempting to following Microsoft's instructions for Protecting a resource server/API using Spring Boot 3.2.1.
application.yml
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      active-directory:
        enabled: true
        credential:
          client-id: <some-id>
        app-id-uri: <some-id>

pom.xml
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory</artifactId>
   <version>5.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>

Now according to the documentation that is all I need to do if I want to use the default security configuration (as stated in option 1 for Spring Cloud Azure 5.x). However, my endpoints are still not protected and I can invoke them with and without a JWT.
If I do as specified in option 2, that is "Option 2: Provide a self-defined configuration." like the following, then it works...but how can I get it to work with option 1 to avoid this boilerplate code.
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
        return http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .headers(headers -> headers.disable())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .with(AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer.aadResourceServer(), Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .build();
    }


You can have a look at this starter I wrote. It works with any OpenID provider. All the "boilerplate" you'll need is setting in properties the JSON-path to the JWT claim(s) you want to be mapped to Spring authorities.

Thanks for the link @ch4mp..but actually really curious on getting Microsoft suggested solution working
